# Does Stanford Core NLP support lemmatization for German?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I found German parse and pos-tag models which are compatible with Stanford Core NLP. However I was not able to get German lemmatization working. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Do you mean "not able to get German lemmatization working" ?

Comment: Do you mind changing the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the version 3.6 is also German supported.
Check it under http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html

Comment: But it **does not support lemmatization** (yet). The sentence splitter also is quite unreliable for German.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, as far as I know no implementation of German lemmatization exists for Stanford CoreNLP.

Answer (score 1):

Even the latest version 4.4.0 of CoreNLP still does not support lemmatization for German. See https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html for reference.