# Lemmatization of Spanish sentences In Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

How can I use Stanford-NLP to lemmatize words or is this even a possibility in coreNLP?

According to this website (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html) Lemmatization is not an option--but I'm hoping that this is a neglected page that needs to be updated.

Additionally, I've seen related questions but about German: [Does Stanford Core NLP support lemmatization for German?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861925/does-stanford-core-nlp-support-lemmatization-for-german)

**How can I lemmatize spanish words in CoreNLP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to GitHub, this is not functionality that exists in Stanford Core NLP.

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/137